# Custom bindable stacklayout should trigger UI when item of ObservableCollection change

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with my custom stacklayout which populates the stacklayout correctly but does not recognizes any changes of any item in the bound observable collection..

This is the code I use for the bindable stacklayout:

```
public class BindableStackLayout : StackLayout
{
    private readonly Label _header;

    public BindableStackLayout()
    {
        _header = new Label();
        Children.Add(_header);
    }

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable), 
        typeof(BindableStackLayout), propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => ((BindableStackLayout)bindable).PopulateItems());

    public DataTemplate ItemDataTemplate
    {
        get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemDataTemplateProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemDataTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemDataTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemDataTemplate), 
        typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(BindableStackLayout));

    public string Title
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
        set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Title), typeof(string), 
        typeof(BindableStackLayout), propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => ((BindableStackLayout)bindable).PopulateHeader());

    private void PopulateItems()
    {
        if (ItemsSource == null)
            return;

        foreach (var item in ItemsSource)
        {
            var itemTemplate = ItemDataTemplate.CreateContent() as Xamarin.Forms.View;
            itemTemplate.BindingContext = item;
            Children.Add(itemTemplate);
        }
    }

    private void PopulateHeader() => _header.Text = Title;
}
```

Which is used like you can find here:

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <h:BindableStackLayout ItemsSource="{Binding MenuHotKeys, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           Style="{StaticResource MenuControlStackLayout}">
        <h:BindableStackLayout.ItemDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Text="{Binding DataA}"
                        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.MenuControlCommand, Source={x:Reference InternalMenuControl}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                        Style="{StaticResource MenuControlButton}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </h:BindableStackLayout.ItemDataTemplate>
    </h:BindableStackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

And in the viewmodel I have this code:

```
private ObservableCollection<ConfigMenuItem> _menuHotKeys;
    public ObservableCollection<ConfigMenuItem> MenuHotKeys
    {
        get => _menuHotKeys;
        set => SetValue(ref _menuHotKeys, value);
    }
```

And the change is here:

```
private async void MenuControlButtonPressed(object sender)
    {
        var menuItem = sender as ConfigMenuItem;

        if (menuItem.ItemId == _expanderId)
        {
            // toggle expanded menu visibility
            var expander = _menuHotKeys.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ItemId == _expanderId);

            var buffer = expander.DataA;
            expander.DataA = expander.DataB;
            expander.DataB = buffer;
        }
        else
        {
            await NavigationHandler.NavigateToMenuItem(menuItem);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I want to toggle the name of the bound button, but the changes does not appear.

I think I have to change something in bindable stacklayout class, but what?

Maybe you can help

@INPC answers:
The ConfigMenuItem in the Collection derives from:

```
public abstract class BaseObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, Expression<Func<T>> property)
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(property);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> changedProperty)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            string name = ((MemberExpression)changedProperty.Body).Member.Name;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

and the viewmodel derives from:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void SetValue<T>(ref T privateField, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(privateField, value))
        {
            privateField = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

As requested in comments the ConfigMenuItem class, code of BaseObject see in the code upside:

```
public class ConfigMenuItem : BaseObject, IConfigMenuItem
{
    public int ItemId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Position
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string DataA
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string DataB
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool IsHotKey
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool IsCustomMenuItem
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} ({DataA} | {DataB ?? "null"})";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your SetValue for `MenuHotKeys` notify on property changed?

Comment: an ObservableCollection only notifies of changes to the Collection - ie, Add and Remove.  Changes to properties in each Item of the Collection need to be handled by implementing INPC on the item class

Comment: The SetValue for MenuHotKeys derives from INPC (question updated).. Also the model in the Collection derives from INPC class.. this is working fine with normal lists and other behaviour, so i believe my issue comes from the bindablestacklayout class.. because there is only a method to populate.. maybe i can register the class to repopulate when item of list is changed or anything else?

Comment: Please post the source code of `ConfigMenuItem` class.

Comment: I think the problem is most likely there, not in the `BindableStackLayout` class.

Comment: @MartinZikmund i've added the requested code of ConfigMenuItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that although your `ConfigMenuItem` class derives from `BaseObject`, all its properties are plain properties and do not tirgger `PropertyChanged` event. You have to rewrite the properties to have a backing field and to trigger the event in their setter. For example:

```
private string _dataA;
public string DataA
{
    get => _dataA;
    set => SetValue(ref _dataA, value);
}
```

My example is using the `SetValue` method from `BaseViewModel`, and I actually think the `BaseObject` class is redundant and you could just use `BaseViewModel` instead. Using `[CallerMemberName]` for property is much more convenient than having additional logic for `Expression<Func<T>>`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was thinking that I have messed up something.. did the changes you recommended and this is working now like expected!

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped :-)